# How to use the states of changed store right after dispatching an action in a component method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use Redux for state management of React JS but I have an event handler relevant to a button in my class component like below:

```js
  handleStartBtn = e => {
    const name = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
    const error = "You must set a value in this field";
    this.props.createPoll(name);
    if (!this.props.currentPoll) return;
    cookies.set("assignments", `EHS_${this.props.currentPoll.uuid}`, {
      path: "/"
    });
    this.props.history.push("/polling");
  };
```

The createPoll function is in my actions file. after creating a poll I dispatched a success function and it hits the store then it changes the currentPoll property. but it seems like it will leave null after calling createPoll dispatched I must clicked on startBtn twice till the store to be updated. how can I use the value of store after dispatch method call?

Comment: have you tried using `async` and `await` ? like `await this.props.createPoll(name);`

Comment: `mapStateToProps?`

Comment: I use mapDispatchToProps for calling my createPoll() action of redux then i used mapStateToProps to get the changes that was happened by createPoll dispatch so i want to call createPoll method and its effects all in one method of my component. like my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `componentDidUpdate()` life cycle method for this issue.

```
handleStartBtn = e => {
    const name = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
    const error = "You must set a value in this field";
    this.props.createPoll(name);
};

componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
 if(prevProps.currentPoll !== this.props.currentPoll){
    cookies.set("assignments", `EHS_${this.props.currentPoll.uuid}`, {
      path: "/"
    });
    this.props.history.push("/polling");
 }
}
```

when you dispatch the action through `this.props.createPoll(name);` you redux state of `currentPoll` will be changed and then this change takes place the `componentDidUpdate` will be triggered and in here you can check it (though a proper condition) and continue what needs to be done after that.